# $.focus() works fine, but sometimes cursor is not shown in low version of browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm developing hybrid app using phonegap and jqm.

In our system, some page have only textarea and submit tag to write something.

We want to focus textarea automatically, when user enter into this page.
(Soft keyboard is shown successfully using native code)

When this page is loaded, $.focus() is called.

It works fine and call callback method for testing.

But my problem is that cursor is not shown in some low version of android.

http://jsfiddle.net/Shxbv/8/

```
// js
$("input, textarea").focus(function(){
    $("div").append("something is focused!!");}
);
$("input").focus();
$("textarea").focus();

// html
<input type="text" tabindex="1">
<!-- <textarea tabindex="1"></textarea> -->
<div></div>
```

Above code is to test focus.

Thanks!!

Comment: It happens in many apps that you need to tap in the text box to get the keyboard to show, even when the text box has focus.

Comment: Use `.trigger('vclick')` or tap or click.

Comment: @Archer thanks your comment. but is there any other alternative to solve this problem or if there is not, i want to know why it happens.

Comment: @Omar thanks your comment. i already have done to use .trigger(). but it does same.